# swift update cell accessory type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to update my table cell accessory type when I tap a cell.
here is the code:

```
var selectedCellArray :[FriendTableViewCell] = []
var friends: [PFUser] = []



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var  selectedCell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as FriendTableViewCell

    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None){

        selectedCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        selectedCellArray.append(selectedCell)
    }else if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){

        selectedCell.accessoryType = .None
        var index = 0
        for cell in selectedCellArray{
            if (cell != selectedCell){
                index++
            }else{
                break
            }
        }

        selectedCellArray.removeAtIndex(index)


    }
    self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)



}
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friend") as? FriendTableViewCell ?? FriendTableViewCell()
    var round = 0
    var friend: AnyObject = self.friends[indexPath.row]


    cell.firstNameLabel.text = friend["firstName"] as? String

    cell.lastNameLabel.text = friend["lastName"] as? String
    println(selectedCellArray)
    round++
    var hasFound = false
    if (self.checkSelectedArray(selectedCellArray, target: cell)){
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }

    cell.firstNameLabel.sizeToFit()
    cell.lastNameLabel.sizeToFit()
    return cell
}
func checkSelectedArray(selectedArray:[FriendTableViewCell], target:FriendTableViewCell) -> Bool{
    for cell in selectedCellArray{
        if cell.isEqual(target){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Also, is there a built-in method like array.contain? Currently, I wrote a function by myself to check if an array has certain element......

Please help me out... I am stuck for this problem for about 8 hours

Comment: You shouldn't store the reference to the cell in your `selectedCellArray` as cells can be reused when the table scrolls.  You can't use the cell's current accessory type for the same reason.  You should store the row number of selected cells.  You can also use an `NSIndexSet`. It gets a bit tricky if you allow row re-ordering, insertion or deletion, however, as you need to update your stored indices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storing the reference to the cell isn't a valid strategy as cells can be re-used when the table scrolls.  You can't use the current cell accessory to indicate selection state for the same reason.

You can use an `NSIndexSet` or a Swift dictionary.  Here is an implementation using a dictionary -

```
var selectedCells :Dictionary<String,PFUser>()

var friends: [PFUser] = []

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let  selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as FriendTableViewCell

    let objectId=friends[indexPath.row].objectId

    if (selectedCells[objectId] != nil){
        selectedCell.accessoryType = .None
        selectedCells.removeValueForKey(objectId)
    } else 
        selectedCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        selectedCells[objectId]=friends[indexPath.row]
    }

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated:false)

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friend") as? FriendTableViewCell ?? FriendTableViewCell()
    var round = 0
    var friend: AnyObject = self.friends[indexPath.row]

    cell.firstNameLabel.text = friend["firstName"] as? String

    cell.lastNameLabel.text = friend["lastName"] as? String

    if (selectedCells[friend.objectId] != nil){
        selectedCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    } else 
        selectedCell.accessoryType = .None
    }

    cell.firstNameLabel.sizeToFit()
    cell.lastNameLabel.sizeToFit()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: in Swift 2.2 use:   var selectedCells = [String: PFUser] ()    to get an empty Dict.